# dual pH sensor system

Tags: isolation, ph

I am working on the development of a dual pH and dual Pt100 sensor interface for a fish farm tank control system.

The tank is expected to have about 75m3 of water, a number of pumps, and feeding systems that are expected to inject noise.

The LMP91200 have been selected as pH sesnor amplifier. Since the distance between the two pH sensors is expected to be about 6-7m and since they are high  I am wondering if there is a need of isolation between the signal conditioning cirquits of the two sensors and isolation with the controller.

Any ideas/proposals for the best approach between the follwoing? Any other suggestion? [image: Isolation #1] - [image: Isolation #2]

Comment: I would try to convert as soon as possible to digital. The more you do on the analog side (isolate, transport over xx meters...) the worse your signal gets.

Comment: To separate potentials from each sensor, to avoid a loop betweeen two cells. http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/hardware-reference-design/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0326.html#rd-overview

Comment: As Marko says, you need isolation to prevent ground loops.  That can be your main problem in an industrial environment.  Consider buying a pair of pH analysers w/isolation built in or one analyser w/dual pH inputs.  Isolation is standard these days.  They could talk to a pc through 4-20 mA current loops.  Also, some equipment has bus networking built in.

Answer (score 1):

I would definately recommend Approach#2. In this approach you are isolating a digital signal, which is a much easier design to get right than trying to isolate 2 low-level analog signals from sensors. Isolation is easy for a digital signal, where you really just need to reliably transport the presence/absense of a voltage above the digital logic threshold. Isolation for an analog signal is difficult, where all kinds of offsets, temperature-related transfer function changes, noise, etc. all influence the measurement accuracy as seen at the ADC. It will be much much easier to design an accurate sensor reading system using Approach#2.

In fact, since the sensors are 6-7m apart, I would suggest Approach#3, where each sensor has a dedicated ADC, and the isolation is applied to each sensor/ADC combination individually.